# How should I state my graduation year?

Tags: cv, graduation

I’ve been MS student and completed all my courses in years 2012-2014, but instead of taking my master’s exam in 2014 (which is requirement for graduation) I took a break. I have defended my master’s thesis and passed the master’s exam this year. During this break out period I wasn’t student, so I am unsure how should I state this on my resume and make it look as good as possible.

Comment: In your field, is it the norm to include all specific dates regarding when you studied (and are there other conventions you know of that are relevant)? I ask because some fields do not care, and would be completely happy with just listing the award and date you were given it (i.e. no further details).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest stating the date ranges during which you were registered as a student, as well as the degree date:

SomeUniversity September 2012 to March 2014 and January 2018, MS SubjectX 2018.

That will presumably match up with the employment section of the CV that will show work during the gap.

Comment: Thank you. I was also wondering whether omitting graduation & study years would be big no-no?

Comment: @Jeg it would be a big no-no. Always include time spans in items on your CV (education and employment).

Comment: @Jeg Why do you want to leave off the graduation and study years?

Comment: So much for "don't accuse OP of wanting to doctor their CV to make it look good".

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I thought that maybe it would make it look less bad. And since it was couple of years ago I am wondering whether professional experience isn't more important than studying years?

Answer (score 0):

Your date of graduation is the one written on your graduation certificate.

If you want to justify your absence, cover letter is the correct place. Not the CV.